# NSubstitute Error UnexpectedArgumentMatcherException

Tags: c#, mocking, nsubstitute

I'm getting the following error:

> NSubstitute.Exceptions.UnexpectedArgumentMatcherException: 'Argument
>   matchers (Arg.Is, Arg.Any) should only be used in place of member
>   arguments. Do not use in a Returns() statement or anywhere else
>   outside of a member call. Correct use:
>   sub.MyMethod(Arg.Any()).Returns("hi") Incorrect use:
>   sub.MyMethod("hi").Returns(Arg.Any())'

When trying to mock out the following interface:

```
public interface IMyDate
{
    DateTime GetDate();
}
```

Here's where I mock it:

```
var myDate = Substitute.For<IMyDate>();
myDate.GetDate().Returns(testDate); // Error thrown here
```

Please can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
var myDate = Substitute.For<IMyDate>();
myDate.GetDate().Returns(new DateTime(2018, 04, 05)); // Error thrown here
```

Gives the same result.

Answer (score 6):

This might be due to a problem with an earlier test. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40924319/906) for some steps for tracking down this issue. I've included a snapshot of that answer below:

> This is most like due to a previous test using an argument matcher
>   against a non-virtual method, or in a Returns statement.
>
> Unfortunately this can be quite tricky to debug. First step is to see
>   if the problem occurs when you run all the test in this fixture. If
>   so, check all uses of Arg.Is|Any in that fixture, starting with the
>   one that runs immediately before the test that fails (if your test
>   framework uses a predictable test order, otherwise you'll need to look
>   at test logs to see what tests proceed the failing one).
>
> If it does not occur with that fixture you'll need to look through the
>   fixtures that run beforehand to see where the left over arg matcher is
>   coming from. It is most likely somewhere near the failing test.

Hope this helps. In positive news the next NSubstitute version (v4) will offer more help in these cases.

See also: [How not to use argument matchers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/#how_not_to_use_argument_matchers).

Answer (score 5):

In our case, a random test was sending this error message, but only when running all the test. We found this error when migrated from 4.6.1 to netcore 3.1.

The problem was that a test class without any substitute was using the `Arg.Any<int>()` expresion, for unkown reason.

**Deleting** this unespected piece of code `Arg.Any<int>()` was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely `testDate` is an argument matcher (`Arg.Is` or `Arg.Any`)

The exception message is telling you just to use argument matchers as member call arguments, not as return values, but you are are using it as return value...

> "Do not use in a Returns() statement or anywhere else outside of a member call"

Try

```
var testDate = new DateTime(); //<-- try setting the desired date as needed
var myDate = Substitute.For<IMyDate>();
myDate.GetDate().Returns(testDate);
```

Reference [NSubstitute: Argument matchers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/)

Comment: It gives the same result.  See update in my question.

Comment: @qwerty I highly doubt that the error will be the same. What is the new error being thrown?

Comment: I just tested it locally and it works fine, as @NKosi said,probably is a different error.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you - it's the same error.  testDate was already a hard-coded date beforehand.

Comment: That is odd, make sure that recompilation works fine and your are not getting some old binaries where the source code was different

Comment: No - tried restarting VS and deleting the bin and obj directories

Answer (score 0):

I faced it problem. And the exception was thrown in one test class (file), but the cause of issue was in different test class (file)

The problem is Arg.Any<>()

```
    [Test]
    public void CaptureAsync_Success()
    {
        Assert.Throws<NotImplementedException>(() => _sut.CaptureAsync(Arg.Any<string>));
    }
```

I fixed this issue using the instance of type **string**

```
    [Test]
    public void CaptureAsync_Success()
    {
        Assert.Throws<NotImplementedException>(() => _sut.CaptureAsync("test"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but the top voted answer hints in the right direction.

The best way to solve this issue is to find exactly where the misuse of NSubstitute is occurring and for that there is the *excellent* package NSubstitute.Analyzers (for C# or for VB) that gives you warnings upon building the project.

Really helpful for me, it pointed me directly to where the issue was.
In my case, I was substituting a class rather than its interface and of course I couldn't use the clever methods on it. Changed it to substitute the interface and worked like a charm.

I hope this is useful to someone else! Just read the warning you get with this package and you'll surely find your way out.

Comment: Unfortunately the analyzer has bugs in other parts of nsubstitute, that's why I had to remove it from my project. It helps, when it does not create false positives.